# How to optimize the implementation of responsive ads on web sites

Tags: responsive-design, ads

I’m struggling with how to implement advertising in an innovative and responsive way as we redesign our 15 year old (ASP) website and move to Wordpress. I am not talking about adsense, this is for internally managed ads. We are currently using Google/DFP but I'm open to alternatives.

I recently read an article by Om Malik (goo.gl/eEigdS) in which he touches on the concept of ‘native ads’ and it made me think others had found me a way out (of the traditional banner ad problem) but he also had the opinion that 'native ads' was a passing fad.

I can’t seem to find much standardized guidance on responsive advertising.  And since CTR is already terrible, I’m open to new ideas. Certainly there are many ways to make ads responsive.  And by there very nature banners seem to act responsive 'out of the box'.  I've even found QA's on Stackoverflow that have codesnipets for responsive ads.  But that isn't really what I'm after.

The challenge is to find a solution that works for multiple screen resolutions, 'designs' and devices.  But also encourages users to click. Current banners are most certainly being ignored. I would love to get away from the standard banner zone technique and try something new and feel like responsive design may have a way out that I'm not seeing.

I'm at the point were I'm close to recommending a 'subscription model' on our site where users could pay a small monthly or annual fee to remove all banner ads. But concepts like this hurt our ability to sell to advertisers (since ad impressions would be down) and also limit our ability to reach users with our own 'house' ads.

I suppose even if we came up with something revolutionary or evolutionary it would be a challenge to bring the advertisers along.  It’s so much easier to create one or more banners and distribute them to a X publishers.

For example, we could require ads (creatives) that are related to content (in some general way) so users see ads that are somewhat similar to the rest of the content on the site. For us this kind of thing is easier as we are a niche site and our advertisers are typically from that niche.

Is there anyone else going through this (or has gone through this) exercise? What sort of creative solution(s) have you come up with and what admanagement tool(s) have you considered or are you using? How have you implemented responsive ads on the site? As a result of this change have you seen a substantial increase in CTR? What was the impact on advertisers (if any) and was it a struggle to bring them along?

Thank you in advanced and sorry if I've been rambling.

Comment: I'm hitting up against pretty similar issues. I've read a few good articles on selling set packages of ads to suit responsive, eg: http://www.markboulton.co.uk/journal/responsive-advertising

But that's not really at the true innovative level.

Comment: Thank you!  Are you moving towards zones that are using CSS to detect resolution?  How are you managing this?  Also, will you be offering packages as suggested in the article or just offering each zone on it's own?

Comment: At the moment, I'm looking at the package option. Treating each page view (Regardless of which banner is served) as a single impression. I'm actually serving all 3 as one impression so if you resize the window you can see all ad blocks, using CSS media queries.


It's a bit of a pain in the butt for reporting using out of the box solutions, so at the moment I'm running it as a custom job.

On another project I'm about to start exploring options with 3rd party services, but I need to ability to manage my inventory, so will see how this goes.

Comment: Which 3rd party services are you looking at?

Comment: I'll be taking a look at a few different options such as Google's Dart stuff, responsive ads (http://www.responsiveads.com/) and whatever else I can find. At the moment I'm really in research phase, haven't really explored any of those options yet at all

Comment: I'm leaning towards this implementation with DFP to be honest - http://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/mobile-advertising-using-responsive-ads

Comment: Now, that's great!  A way to keep our DFP and be responsive.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to see the ads in action following this method: http://www.theswitchreport.com.au/